# Built-in laptop monitor is not detected anymore

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, monitor

## The problem

The built-in monitor of my laptop is not detected and goes blank at the login screen.

However an external monitor connected to the VGA port is correctly detected and gets recognized as the primary display.

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Note that `eDP-1`, the built-in laptop screen, is seen as not being connected.

I have `Xorg` version 1.15.1 installed and my kernel version is `Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu`. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

My laptop is a Dell Latitude E6510 with an Nvidia graphic card and I am using the so called `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` (open-source) driver.

The laptop screen used to work and the problem only appeared after a hard power-off of the laptop while it was in sleep mode.

The built-in screen is correctly recognized in low resolution when I boot in failsafe graphic mode from GRUB.

## What I have tried

- Reset the X settings using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`
- Try to use the Nvidia proprietary driver through the "Additional Drivers". When I hit "Apply changes", the window goes idle for a second and then goes back with the open-source driver selected "as if" nothing happened.
- Use `xrandr` to force the configuration of the built-in display. For instance: `xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto`. This fails silently.
- Generate an old school `xorg.conf` using `X -configure` and play with the settings under `Section Screen`.

All of the above failed. Any advice on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... The problem actually came from the hardware. I dismounted the laptop and cleaned up the connector between the graphics card and the built-in monitor (see below)

[image]

After that everything came back to normal.

Comment: Same issue here. That's a scary fix, I can't open my laptop like that.